# How to convert an OutputStream into a string?

Tags: java, java-me, outputstream

This is my client code (J2ME):

```
SocketConnection sc = (SocketConnection) Connector.open("socket://localhost:4444");
sc.openOutputStream().write("test".getBytes());
sc.close();
```

And this is my server code (J2SE):

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
```

How would I go about creating a string representation of `os`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`InputStream` and `OutputStream` are for byte sequences. `Reader` and `Writer` are for character sequences, like `String`s.

To turn an `OutputStream` into a `Writer`, do `new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream)`, or *much* better, use `new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, Charset)` to specify a `Charset`, which describes a way of converting between characters and bytes.

(The other direction, `InputStreamReader`, is similar.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean I should create an OutputStreamWriter using the OutputStream I get from clientSocket? If so, what do I do with it? How to I get the content of the output stream?

Comment: You don't "get contents of an output stream."  You get contents of an _input_ stream.  That's...why it's called input.  (In which case you'll probably want an `InputStreamReader`, not an `OutputStreamWriter`.)